# Fast uniformity test within a ball.

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Assume I have a dataset lies within a ball centered around the origin, I want to test the uniformity of the point distributed in the ball. In addition, I have all the distances to the origin computed as a side-product from previous step. I am not familiar with statistical test, what are natural choices of tests can I try?

A naive test I can think of is to compute the mean compare it with the origin, the farther the mean is deviated from the origin, the more skewed the dataset is.

Or, I can compute the skew, but this doesn't take advantage of the distances I already have.

I know this may depend on how accurate and solid I need it to be, I need a quick test that doesn't have to be very tight, but I'd like to have it based on well-known theory.

Thanks

Comment: What in particular are you trying to measure about this data set?  How close they are together? How evenly spread?  How close they are *to eachother*, or how close they are *from the origin*?  Regards

Comment: my major interest is to find out points that are far away from their nearest neighbors.